# canceling or rejecting a promise vuejs after response interceptor

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am new to VueJS but stuck trying to handle a promise after interceptor is triggered.

I have a component called orders (orders/index.vue) and in this component I have a `created` function as such:

```
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('user/GETORDERS')
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status === 200) {
          this.data = response.data.data
        }
      })
  }
```

This `dispatch` call is mapped to an axios function which calls our API to get the data:

```
export async function getorders() {
  return apiClient
    .get('/get-orders')
    .then(response => {
      return response
    })
    .catch(err => {
      return err.response
    })
}
```

I have an interceptor as such:

```
apiClient.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => {
    if (error.config.url !== '/login' && error.config.url !== '/logout' && error.response.status === 401) {
      store.dispatch('user/HANDLE_401')
      return Promise.reject(error)
    } else {
      throw error
    }
  })
```

What I noticed is that when the 401 is triggered (a user is on the app, session expires but they try to navigate to another part of the dashboard, they are logged out as expected (`HANDLE_401`)). Still, it appears that the `created` function inside the index.vue component is being triggered after the `Promise.reject` occurs. I added a console.log() above the if statement in the `.then` clause to test it. Am I handling the rejection properly? Shouldn't the promise be canceled and no further evaluation occur? Why does the `.then` trigger if not?

Answer (score 0):

The second `then` triggers because you are `catch`-ing the error from the first `then`. So the first Promise is rejected, you catch this rejection and return `err.response` - so the second Promise continues normally. If you want your first rejection to propagate through the Promise's chain - you should only add `catch` on your top-level Promise. Or you should `throw` an error inside your lower-level `catch` block(s).